# How can I get last column in pandas.DataFrame when line have different length?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, text-parsing

How can I get last column in  pandas.DataFrame  when line have different length?
I new in Python and Pandas.

```
splitMessage = pd.DataFrame(array_data)
print(splitMessage)

    [repair, materials, rub]
    [food, pizza, rub]
    [services, delivery, rub]
    [donation, donation, usd]
    [repair, work, rub]
    [coffee, usd]
    [lunch, rub]
    [lunch,usd]
    [dentist, usd]
    [usd]
```

I need only last elements  [currensy] in column format:

```
[rub]
[rub]
[rub]
[usd]
[rub]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If each element in the column of the dataframe is a list, you can get last element using:

```
splitMessage[column_name].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

If you need the output to be list as you mentioned use:

```
splitMessage[column_name].apply(lambda x: list(x[-1]))
```